# Use Regex to identify patterns in UK Postcodes

Tags: regex, replace, postal-code

For any UK postal code I want to replace all letters with capital A and all digits with 9.

For example
CH5 1EF would become AA9 9AA
EC1N 4DH would become AA9A 9AA

Is this possible in a single RegEx.Replace or would I have to have two separate RegEx.Replace statements?

Comment: you have to use regex? or anything that's solves your problem is ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said what language you are using, I'll just give the regex.

Two operations:

1. Matching regex: `[A-Z]` and replace with: `A`
2. Matching regex: `\d` and replace with: `9`

In java, it would look like:

```
String postcode = "CH5 1EF";
String result = postcode.replaceAll("[A-Z]", "A").replaceAll("\\d", "9");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need two replaces for this: first replace all [A-Za-z] with "A" then replace all [0-9] with "9".  Even if there was a way to do this with a single expression it would be a nightmare to read and maintain it.